# How to splice #2 copper THHN to #2 aluminium SER in a junction box?

Tags: electrical

This is going to a 100amp subpanel in a new shed. The plan is to use #2 AWG THHN copper (can't find #3) in the conduit so it's easier to pull and then switch to #2 SER inside so it can go in the ceiling/walls. Should I just use a large plastic junction box inside where the conduit terminates and then splice the aluminum and copper together, I'm confused on what type of connector to use for this.

Comment: Why 2AWG for the SER instead of 1AWG, and why 2AWG *copper* for the run in the conduit instead of 1AWG *aluminum*?

Comment: If the answer is splice in a box, use a steel box.

Comment: Why not bury the conduit to the shed & continue the run of THHN? Please edit to provide more details, as your question is sure to raise more questions than get answers...

Comment: What size is the box you're trying to splice inside, for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question without a bunch of other questions.

I would use a Polaris connector, I usually stock 2/0 size 2 hole up to 4 hole. The 2/0 size is listed all the way down to 14 awg.

Make sure you choose one that is copper/ aluminum there are some that are copper only. A bit spendy but only a screwdriver or Allen (hex) is needed.
Polaris is a brand these connectors are commonly called I think the big orange box store carries Morris but if you search for Polaris connectors they will show up.

Sticker shock, is the next issue with these, but they are all you need.
There are split bolts rated for copper aluminum but then the cambric, liner less and standard tape are needed with some anti oxide compound and knowing how to, the Polaris is simple.